# escape string containing named subpattern with preg_quote

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to use `preg_quote` and ignore named subpatterns to be escaped ?
For example :

`/login/?next=(?P<next_url>.*)`

would be escaped to

`\/login\/\?next\=(?P<next_url>.*)`

instead of

`\/login\/\?next\=\(\?P\<next_url\>\.\*\)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a workaround by implementing my own function:

```
protected function escapeUrlPattern($pattern) {
    $chars = array('/', '=', '-', '.', '\\', '+', '*', '?', '^', '$', '{', '}', '!', '<', '>', '|', ':',);
    $patternChars = str_split($pattern);
    $idle = false;
    $escapedPattern = "";
    foreach ($patternChars as $char) {
        if ($char == "(" || $char == "[")
            $idle = true;

        if (!$idle && in_array($char, $chars))
            $char = "\\" . $char;

        $escapedPattern .= $char;

        if ($char == ")" || $char == "]")
            $idle = false;
    }
    return $escapedPattern;
}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You could build the regular expression up in separate parts in order to only `preg_quote` the parts of the expression you want.

For example:

```
$pattern = preg_quote('\/login\/?next=').'(?P<next_url>.*)';
```

Comment: The problem is that the url is user-defined so I can't have this approach

Comment: i'm confused, you say the "url" is user-definded, but i thought `\/login\/?next=(?P<next_url>.*)` was a pattern not a url? are you saying that the whole thing is input by the user?

Comment: Yes you're right, `/login/?next=(?P<next_url>.*)` is a user-defined pattern. What I want is to pre_quote this pattern and perform a preg_match with this pattern and an url. Is it more clear ?